# String matching in Perl for multiple patterns

Tags: perl, if-statement, string-matching

I have a string, and when I check it against with the variable its not giving me expected result. By using pattern matching mechanism it works fine.

Is this expected behavior in Perl. If not, how to resolve this without using pattern matching.

Code Below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my $day_of_week = "Monday";

if (($day_of_week ne "Monday") or ($day_of_week ne "Tuesday")){
    print "In If. Today is $day_of_week.\n";
} else {
    print "In else part\n";
}
```

This should give output as:

```
In else part
```

But its giving me:

```
In If. Today is Monday.
```

When I change the `if` condtion with pattern matching like below, it works fine.

```
if ($day_of_week !~ /Monday|Tuesday) {
```

My concern is why the string matching is not working as per the condition. Am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: I think you mean `if (not (($day_of_week eq "Monday") or ($day_of_week eq "Tuesday")))` , not what you wrote: `if (($day_of_week ne "Monday") or ($day_of_week ne "Tuesday"))`

Comment: @HåkonHægland you're right. that means multiple patterns will not work for `ne` condition?

Comment: ne : Returns true if the left argument is stringwise not equal to the right argument.
or : Called Logical OR Operator. If any of the two operands are non zero then then condition becomes true.
in your case `("$day_of_week" ne "Monday")` return zero but for this case `("$day_of_week" ne "Tuesday") return 1 so conditon becomes true.
and: operator: Called Logical AND operator. If both the operands are true then then condition becomes true.

Comment: something like  `$foo ne 'bar' or $foo ne 'baz'`  is always going to be true; or means true if either operand is true, and `$foo` is always going to be `ne` at least one of your multiple choices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the convoluted composite condition that got you --

```
$day_of_week ne "Monday"  # FALSE but 
$day_of_week ne "Tuesday" # TRUE
```

so you're testing

```
if (FALSE or TRUE)  #--> true
```

That's why it's recommended to try to always "straighten" those conditions.

So to test that it's neither Monday nor Tuesday

```
if ( $day_of_week ne "Monday" and $day_of_week ne "Tuesday" )
```

This is much harder to get confused.

---

The logic you probably meant need be encoded as

```
if (not ($day_of_week eq "Monday" or $day_of_week eq "Tuesday") )
```

Forming one large composite condition that is then negated is often clearer than the alternative, but not in this case in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The following is always true:

> it isn't Monday, OR it isn't Tuesday

- On Monday, it isn't Tuesday, so it's true (`F OR T = T`)
- On Tuesday, it isn't Monday, so it's true (`T OR F = T`)
- On Wednesday, it's neither (`T OR T = T`)

You want

> it isn't Monday, AND it isn't Tuesday

```perl
if ($day_of_week ne "Monday" && $day_of_week ne "Tuesday") {
    print "Today is $day_of_week.\n";
} else {
    print "Otherwise\n";
}
```

or

```perl
if ($day_of_week eq "Monday" || $day_of_week eq "Tuesday") {
    print "Otherwise\n";
} else {
    print "Today is $day_of_week.\n";
}
```

---

> *When I change the if condtion with pattern matching like below, it works fine.*

That's because

> it isn't Monday or Tuesday

isn't the same thing as

> it isn't Monday, or it isn't Tuesday

We can prove this.

```
$day_of_week !~ /Monday|Tuesday/
```

is equivalent to

```
!( $day_of_week =~ /Monday|Tuesday/ )
```

which is equivalent to

```
!( $day_of_week =~ /Monday/ || $day_of_week =~ /Tuesday/ )
```

which is equivalent to

```
!( $day_of_week =~ /Monday/ ) && !( $day_of_week =~ /Tuesday/ )
```

(as per [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

which is equivalent to

```
$day_of_week !~ /Monday/ && $day_of_week !~ /Tuesday/
```

Notice how AND is used, but you used OR.